# Import Flat Data with Multiple Delimiters

Tags: sql-server, flat-file

My imported flat file has been imported into SQL with comma delimiters.
An example of my text file looks like:

```
Location\Floor\Room,Date,Value
```

After import:

```
Column 1            | Column 2 | Column 3
Location\Floor\Room | Date     | Value
```

I would like my table to look as follows:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5
Location | Floor    | Room     | Date     | Value
```

Are there any ways that I can achieve like above?

Comment: let say you have Location\Floor\Room\Dining, so there's a need for additional column?

Comment: The data has been structured that it wont have "\Dining"
However, in a case if there is, Column 3 will be Room\Dining.

Comment: you need sql query for this?

Comment: i will be using the sql data to query in powerbi

Comment: How many (max) values there are in the not divided string ?

Comment: You mean in the first column? In this case, there are 3(Location,floor and room). However in my real data, I have 5 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SSIS - SQL Server Integration Service` can also be used for this use case.

What you basically need is a two step transformation process where you load your input file in an interim table which allows a `comma` as a standard delimiter.

Once, you have you interim table available and with records (including the ones with `backslash`) you should then use a `Derived Column Task` in SSIS and create a custom logic based on `SUBSTRING() and FINDSTRING()` methods to create new columns to split the string based on `backslash`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of this solution.

```
select t2.col1
    , t2.col2
    , substring(t2.col3, charindex('\', t2.col3, len(t2.col2) + len(t2.col1)) + 1, len(t2.col3) - (len(t2.col2) + len(t2.col1) + 2))
    , t2.[value], t2.[date] 
from (
        select t1.col1, substring(t1.main, len(t1.col1) + 2
            , charindex('\', t1.main, len(t1.col1) + 2) - (len(t1.col1) + 2)) as col2
            , t1.main as col3, t1.[value], t1.[date] 
        from (
            select substring(column1, 0, charindex('\', column1)) as col1, column1 as main, [date], [value] 
            from tableA
            ) t1
        ) t2
```

Comment: this kinda works but how do I update the table using this query?

Comment: yes, you can update the table. just join this query

Answer (score 0):

This working for MAX 5 value of undivided string

> val1\val2\val3\val4\val5

```
    select [1] as col1, [2] as col2, [3] as col3, [4] as col4, [5] as col5, col2 as col7, col3 as col8
    from (
        select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by col1 order by col1) rowid, col1, col2, col3, value
        from <MyTable>
        cross apply string_split(s.col1, '\')
    ) as tbl
    pivot (
        max(value) for rowid in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
    ) as pv
```